# number format exception when using integer.parseInt java

Tags: java, delimiter

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class reader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char rbracket=')';
        char lbracket='(';
        char rsbracket=']';
        char lsbracket='[';
        String delimiter="\\D";
        String[] ar;
        char start = 0,end=0;
        int x[]=new int[2];
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)))
        {
            String c=reader.readLine();
            for(int i=0;i<c.length();i++)
            {
                if(c.charAt(i)==rbracket)start=rbracket;
                else if (c.charAt(i)==rsbracket)start=rsbracket;
                else if(c.charAt(i)==lbracket)end=lbracket;
                else if(c.charAt(i)==lsbracket)end=lsbracket;
            }
            ar=c.split(delimiter);
            System.out.println(start);
            System.out.println(end);
            for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++)
            {
                x[i]=Integer.parseInt(ar[i].trim());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I am trying to read an input `(90,100)` of this format, i need to read both the brackets and the range inside. check if the bracket is `(` `[` and then set min and max range for the numbers inside `(=exclusive` of the number and `[=inclusive` . i am trying to read into a string check for the braces and then split the string into the numbers and save into an integer string to work with.

I am however not able to convert the string into the integer string after the split getting a number format exception. Please help, where is the mistake?

Comment: Did you check the input?.. Is it as expected?

Comment: did you tryed to debug it?

Comment: Check the value of `ar[i].trim()` You will easily get what the issue.

Comment: Print the content of before converting to integer. `System.out.println(ar[i]);`

Comment: TheLostMind: yes the input is as expected.

Comment: @abishek: when i print i do get just the numbers , thats why i am not sure why i get the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `ar=c.split(delimiter);` returns the following array (for input `"(90,100)"`):

```
["", "90", "100"]
```

So that first `Integer.parseInt` call is failing.

A better solution may be to use a regex to parse and validate the input and extract the digits:

```
    String c = "(90,100)";
    int[] x = new int[2];
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([(\\[])(\\d+),(\\d+)([)\\]])");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(c);
    if (!m.matches()) {
        // input is invalid
        System.out.println("Bad input string: " + c);
    } else {
        // input is valid
        char start = m.group(1).charAt(0);
        char stop = m.group(4).charAt(0);
        x[0] = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
        x[1] = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
        for (int y : x) {
            System.out.println(y);
        }
    }
```

Explanation of the regex:

- `([(\\[])` means match either a `(` or a `[` character; the outer brackets define a [capture group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg), which is a subset of the matched string that we can retrieve using [`m.group(1)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)) (`1` as it's the first group in the regex).  Note that the third character here (i.e., the second '(') doesn't need to be escaped with \ because it is not counted as a special character when used inside a [custom character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cc).
- `(\\d+)` match one or more digits; the brackets define our second capture-group which we can retrieve using `m.group(2)`
- `,` match a comma
- `(\\d+)` match one or more digits; the brackets define our third capture-group which we can retrieve using `m.group(3)`
- `([)\\]])` match either a `)` or a `]` character; the outer brackets define our fourth capture-group which we can retrieve using `m.group(3)`

Comment: sounds like a good option. I will get input from the user in the same format so i can use a loop and get it as a string and then check. I dont need to check for spaces in the regex though. so i guess i will have to have a pattern of Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[(\\[](\\d+),(\\d+)[)\\]]"); right?

Comment: thank you regex worked like a charm. When i printed the ar though i only got 90 and 100, so i wasnt aware of the sapce.. how did u figure that out?

Comment: No problem.  Yes, just remove the `\\s*` to remove support for spaces.  You can also wrap the bits that match brackets in `()` to capture those, too, to save you having to loop through the string to figure out which have been used.

Comment: I'm guessing when you printed out the array you passed each item in it to `System.out.println`?  If so, you would have gotten a blank line being printed for the first item, as it's an empty string.  A neat trick to spot those is using something like `System.out.println(ar[i] + " (" + ar[i].length + ")");` when printing an array of strings.  I figured it out because I could just see that's what was happening (I have been using Java for over 7 years now, and other languages prior to that).

Comment: okay i understod that [ (//[] means ( or [ what do i have to do to group that? and how can i parse it?

Comment: Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((\\[)\\s*(\\d+)\\s*,\\s*(\\d+)\\s*()\\])");
      Matcher m = p.matcher(c);
      if (!m.matches())
          System.out.println("Bad input string: " + c);
      } else  
         start=(char) Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
         min = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
         max = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
         end=(char)Integer.parseInt(m.group(4));
         
      }
      if (start==lbracket)min=min+1;
      else start=lsbracket;
      if (end==rbracket)max=max-1;
      else end=rsbracket;
      System.out.println(min+" "+max); this says invalid!

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how to capture the brackets.  Note that `m.group(int)` returns the substring of the original string which matches the given group number; so now `m.group(1)` will return either `"("` or `"["`, which are single character Strings; to get the char value of that single character, we therefore need to do a `charAt(0)`.  Full details of how regexes work in Java is beyond the scope of the question.  Check out the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) and feel free to ask another question if you need help.

Answer (score 1):

Although you're finding out what types of brackets are used in your input, you're not removing them from your string. Therefore, when you split your string, you'll obtain both of the numbers but also have the brackets there too. `Integer.parseInt` won't parse brackets, so this is where your error is coming from.

If you encounter something like this again, try printing out different variables - it's the easiest way to check that the values of variables are what you think they are.

Comment: `"\\D"` as delimeter split also on brackets, so it is not case here

Comment: yes m.cekiera i used \\D so thats not the issue here.